# DART POLYMER: How I can update a property from a custom element by another?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I would like to update a property **labels** in a custom element (**signin_element**) by another custom element (**localized_element**). But the property **labels** have changed type from Map to String during the operation.

Explanation:

1/ Just after the application start, the custom element (signin-element) update the property **labels** with a Map (see the file signin.dart).

2/ After the custom element **localized-element** is initialized, the property **labels** is updated with a new Map from an external json file. The method update can't assign a new Map to the property **labels**, because is now a **String**.

Chromium return warnings:

> Attributes on signin-element were data bound prior to Polymer
> upgrading the element. This may result in incorrect binding types.
>
> Attributes on localized-element were data bound prior to Polymer
> upgrading the element. This may result in incorrect binding types.

And finally return an error:

```dart
Class 'String' has no instance method '[]='.
```

[image]

**Signin.html:**

```dart
<core-animated-pages selectedindex="0" notap id="core_animated_pages">
    <section id="section1" layout horizontal active center-justified center>
      <core-card id="core_card" layout vertical>
        <paper-input label="Your email addres" floatinglabel id="email_input"></paper-input>
        <paper-input label="Your password" floatinglabel id="password_input"></paper-input>
        <div id="div" layout horizontal end-justified>
          <paper-fab icon="check" id="paper_fab"></paper-fab>
        </div>
        <h2>{{labels['hello']}}</h2>
      </core-card>
    </section>
  </core_animated_pages>
  
  <localized-element id="l10n" locale={{locale}} labels={{labels}}></localized-element>
```

**signin.dart**

```dart
@CustomTag('signin-element')
class Signin extends PolymerElement {
  
  @published String locale = 'en';
  
  @observable Map labels = toObservable({
    'hello': 'Hello 1'
  });
  
  Signin.created() : super.created();
}
```

**localized.dart**

```dart
@CustomTag('localized-element')
class Localized extends PolymerElement {
  
  @published String locale = 'en';
  @published Map labels;
  
  Localized.created() : super.created();
  
  ready() {
    super.ready();
    _loadTranslations();
  }
  
  update() {
    if (!_l10n.containsKey(locale)) return;
    
    var l10n = _l10n[locale];

    labels['hello'] = l10n['hello'];
  }
  
  List locales = ['en', 'fr'];
  _loadTranslations() {
    locales.forEach((l10n)=> _loadLocale(l10n));
  }

  Map _l10n = {};
  _loadLocale(_l) {
    HttpRequest.getString('i18n/translation_${_l}.json')
      .then((res) {
        _l10n[_l] = JSON.decode(res);
        update();
      })
      .catchError((Error error) {
        print(error.toString());
      });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to change

```dart
@published Map labels;
```

in localized.dart to

```dart
@PublishedProperty(reflect: true) Map labels;
```

the same with `locale`

see 
[Google Groups - Dart Web Development - PSA: Polymer 0.11.0 @published properties no longer reflect to attributes by default](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!searchin/web/publishedattribute/web/rzJ9oVUZHTU/pnXQg3hodmMJ)

Comment: Hi Günter, thanks to help me again :). I think you talk about PublishedProperty and not PublishedAttribute right? If yes, the problem is always the same. I can't update labels with a new Map because the type is a string.

Comment: Can you a publish a working example that allows to reproduce the problem on GitHub? Thanks for the hint, I updated my answer.

Comment: Voilà: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7kQatBvjEOzMTVFN1ZZeEdab3c/edit?usp=sharing To save the full zip you can use File -> download

Comment: I created a pull request with several comments https://github.com/olituks/dart-polymer-sample/pull/1
The main culprit were missing imports.

Comment: I think a new badge need to be create specifically for you "Dart Magician". It's work ! I publish the solution for the other people with the same question. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Günter found the solution and I push the code change in case of you encounter the same issue.

First, update polymer dependencies to dev:

```
polymer: '>=0.12.0-dev <0.13.0'
```

Second, replace @published from localized.dart

```
@PublishedProperty(reflect: true) String locale = 'en';
@PublishedProperty(reflect: true) Map labels;
```

and in the file signin.dart

```
@PublishedProperty(reflect: true)
```